# Rails 7 - OS X - Searchkick - The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, ruby-on-rails-7

`Ruby 3.0.3`
`Rails 7.0.0.alpha2`
`OS X 12.2.1`

I installed on local Searchkick and followed the [instructions](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#getting-started) to reindex the `Company` model but I have this error.

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
end
```

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "MacBook-Pro-West.local",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_guillaume",
  "cluster_uuid" : "byYWvBdJRqumyBrdu_Od-w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "e5acb99f822233d62d6444ce45a4543dc1c8059a",
    "build_date" : "2022-02-23T22:20:54.153567231Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

```sh
$ rake searchkick:reindex:all

Reindexing Company...
The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.
rake aborted!
Elasticsearch::UnsupportedProductError: The client noticed that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not support this unknown product.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to downgrade the version of `elasticsearch` to `7.14`.

Comment: how did you do the downgrade?

Comment: @Chris I wrote `gem "elasticsearch", "< 7.14"` inside Gemfile and ran `bundle install`